# How to properly represent Long value `&HFFFF` in Hex literal/notation?

Tags: vb6, hex

For, the following code:

```
Dim lLength As Long
lLength = 350
If lLength <= &HFFFF Then
    MsgBox "True"
EndIf
```

`lLength <= &HFFFF` is returning `False`.

My guess is that `&HFFFF` is interpreted as `Integer` value `-1` and therefore the statement evaluates to `False`.

I also tried `&H0000FFFF` but the IDE removes the leading `0000` and I also tried `&HFFFFL` which causes compile error.

Can I represent `65535` in Hex literal in VB6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try explicitly marking it as a `Long` with a trailing ampersand &.

```
&HFFFF&
```

`&HFFFF` without the trailing ampersand is an `Integer` literal, and `Integer` in VB6 is a signed 2-byte integer with a range of -32,768 to +32,767.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. That is because &HFFFF is converted to a signed integer with a range of -32,768 to +32,767.

Explicitly convert it to long using an &.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox CLng(&HFFFF) '--> -1
    MsgBox CLng(&HFFFF&) '--> 65535
End Sub
```